# comment_form() not working

Tags: php, html, forms, wordpress, comments

Here's my `single.php`:

```
<?php get_header(); ?>

<?php

if ( have_posts() ) :
    while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();
         the_content();
         comments_template();
    endwhile;
endif;
?>


<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

And here's my `comments.php`:

```
<h2>Comments</h2>

<?php
wp_list_comments();
comment_form(array('title_reply'=>'Leave a Comment',
                   'comment_notes_before'=>'',
                   'comment_notes_after'=>''));
?>
```

`wp_list_comments()` is working properly, but `comment_form()` returns nothing. How can I make the comment form appear?

Comment: Have you verified the single.php template is being used?

Comment: Yes. As I said, wp_list_comments() works, and the only place comments.php is references is from single.php.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It turns out comments were disabled for some (but not all) posts I'd imported from another WordPress instance. Once I enabled comments, these functions worked properly.

Comment: Funny enough, I had the exact same problem. If you stumble upon this, make sure comments are not only enabled for the whole site, but for the specific post you are trying also!